# Why does this API request return different things with node-fetch than with node's inbuilt fetch?

Tags: node.js, next.js, fetch-api, node-fetch

I have a node app which sends an api request to trigger a bet on Manifold (a fake betting site).

When I use node-fetch it makes a bet.
When I use the inbuilt fetch it returns an old version of the bet if there is one (possibly caching a previous HTTP response?). Restarting the node server does not resolve this issue - it still appears to return old responses.

Nothing else changes except commenting or uncommenting the import for node-fetch (line 3).

If I run the same request in postman it makes the bet.

Code in api/placebet/routes.ts

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';

import fetch from 'node-fetch';

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const body = await request.json();
  
  const sendTime = Date.now();

  console.log('placeBet called with body:', body.apiKey, body.betAmount, body.outcomeToBuy, body.marketID);
  
  const res = await fetch('https://manifold.markets/api/v0/bet', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Key ${body.apiKey}`,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      amount: body.betAmount,
      outcome: body.outcomeToBuy,
      contractId: body.marketID,
    }),
  });
  
  if (!res.ok) {
    const errorDetails = await res.json();
    console.error(errorDetails);
    return NextResponse.json({error: "Error placing the bet"}, {status: 500 });
  }
  
  const data = await res.json();
  
  // Check if the bet's timestamp is before sendTime
  const betTimestamp = data.fills[0].timestamp;

  if (betTimestamp < sendTime) {
    console.error('Error: Bet timestamp is before sendTime');
    console.log(data);
    return NextResponse.json({error: "Bet timestamp is before sendTime"}, {status: 500 });
  }

  console.log("Bet response", data)

  return NextResponse.json(data)
}
```

Comment: Which node version are you using? When comment out import from `node-fetch` you are using node core fetch, which is experimental (also not sure why there's a difference in the response)

Answer (score 0):

This is because the built-in `fetch` function caching the HTTP response.

You can try using `'cache-control': 'no-cache'` in your request header, this will make sure your response is not cached and that a new response is generated each time you make a request.

your `POST` method will look like this:

```
const res = await fetch('https://manifold.markets/api/v0/bet', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': `Key ${body.apiKey}`,
    'cache-control': 'no-cache', // add this line to disable caching
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    amount: body.betAmount,
    outcome: body.outcomeToBuy,
    contractId: body.marketID,
  }),
});
```